# How can I have conditional parameter value in Azure Workbook?

Tags: azure, parameters, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks, azure-subscription

How can I have conditional parameter value in Azure Workbook?

I want to have one parameter called environment. It has some text values. E.g. it has two values `test` and `production`.

Also, I want to have two other parameters: subscription and app_insights.

Now, I want to select the subscription and app_insights values automatically based on the environment parameter value.

So, here is how I am trying to select the test subscription for the subscription parameter when the environment parameter is `test`:

```
summarize by subscriptionId
| project subscriptionId=strcat("/subscriptions/", subscriptionId),
selected = case("{environment}" == "test" and subscriptionId == "test subscription id", true, false)
```

[image]

But it seems that the environment parameter does not get substituted for the `"{environment}"` placeholder. If I remove the `"{environment}" == "test"` check, then the test subscription gets selected as expected.

How can I use one parameter to decide the value of another parameter? Is there a better way to achieve what I want? Preferably I also want the subscription and app_insights parameters not to be shown to the user of the workbook and prevent them from being edited manually.

Comment: also, to hide the parameters you can also use the setting "hide parameter in reading mode"

Comment: Do you still need an answer for this? I just built this functionality

Comment: yes, would be nice to have answer for that

Comment: @manymanymore I added an answer below, I hope you find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example which illustrates how a parameter can be conditional upon another.

---

Let's say we have a parameter named `Environment`, of type `Options group` which gets data from the following JSON:

```
[
    { "value":"'dev'", "label":"dev", "selected":true },
    { "value":"'prod'", "label":"prod" }
]
```

then, we can create a secondary parameter which will return a certain list if `dev` is selected, and a different one if `prod` is selected. This second parameter is of type `Dropdown` and is configured to run an Azure resource graph query across all subscriptions.

```
resources
| extend dev_subs = dynamic([
  "dev-sub1",
  "dev-sub2"
  ])
| extend prod_subs = dynamic([
  "prod-sub1",
  "prod-sub2"
  ])
| extend selection = {Environment}
| extend output = iff(selection == "dev", dev_subs, prod_subs)
| project output
| mv-expand output
| distinct tostring(output)
```

when `dev` is selected in the first parameter, the second parameter will show a dropdown with options `dev-sub1` and `dev-sub2`; when `prod` is selected, the second parameter will show a dropdown with options `prod-sub1` and `prod-sub2`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is 100% supported.

Parameters have to be declared before they are referenced, and then parameters can be referenced left to right, just like code.  Order is important in both steps and parameters.

If you open the "Resource Picker" sample in Workbooks in Azure Monitor:
[image: dependencies]

- there's a hidden parameter of which resource type to show that the subscription picker and resource picker depends on
- everything after subscriptions depends on the selected subscriptions, etc.
- the resource picker depends on which resource groups are selected, etc
- the grid below this depends on resource type, subs, and resources selected, etc.

if you look at the exact query for the resources parameter here, its query text is:

```
Resources
| where type in~({ResourceTypes})
| extend resourceGroupId = strcat('/subscriptions/', subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup)
| where resourceGroupId in~({ResourceGroups}) or '*' in~({ResourceGroups})
| order by name asc
| extend Rank = row_number()
| project value = id, label = name, selected = Rank <= 10, group = resourceGroup
```

Where you can see that the `ResourceGroups` parameter and the `ResourceTypes` parameter are both referenced in the query, and replaced at query time.  The `Subscriptions` parameter is selected in the ARG query's subscription field.

If a parameter isn't being replaced in the query, then that parameter doesn't *exist* before that query (or the parameter is not marked required and has no value, so it gets replaced as an empty string).

while editing a query step, the toolbar in the upper right corner of that step has an item to open up the query with all the parameters replaced in the appropriate view (the Resource Graph Explorer blade, or Logs query blade, or ADX query site, etc) so you can see exactly how the parameters were replaced.

Comment: So, I have a drop down with my customly provided text (i.e. the `test` and `production` values). How can I select a subscription depending on that selected text? It is not clear from your answer how to access the previous parameters values in a parameter definition.

Comment: how you reference a parameter really depends on what the paramter is and how you use it.  if you're trying to filter subscriptions by something, you'd use a subscription picker parameter, normally you'd use an ARG query to search for subscriptions meeting some criteria, like `resourcecontainers | where type =~ "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
| where tags contains "{parameterName}"
// or | where name contains "{parameterName}"
| project id` or whatever?

Comment: in general, parameters are formatted into query text with the `{parameterName}` syntax, but depending on the type of parameter, like time range, or resource params, you might pick the parameter instead of a value from a dropdown, etc.

Comment: Could you, please, read my question again. You are not answering the most important part of it. I have the text parameter `environment`. I want to use it to decide the value for another variables (subscription and app insights in this case). How can I do that? I noted in my question that simply typing the `{environment}` does not seem to work. So, unless my question is answered I am going to downvote this answer. Thanks.

Comment: as i said: `{environment}` will work if the environment parameter is declared before you use it.  Can you post the exact json of your parameters step (or the whole workbook content), to verify exactly what you are doing?  i updated the example to show that the virtual machines parameter *is* referencing parameters in its query content and that this is possible.